# Passing dynamic initial value to riverpod provider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, riverpod, flutter-state

I have a usecase as follow: a screen with initial filter object, this screen is used multiple times with different filter configuration, what I need to achieve is to pass an initial different filter object for each instance from this screen to riverpod notifier provider then I can change the state of this filter using the provider, how I can do that?

I have tried to pass a filter object to the build method but this didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide whether you want only one filter for that provider at a time, or whether you want many providers with their own filters.  If the latter, pass something about the filter in as a family key.  If the first, then have the build method of the provider consume (ref.watch) another provider that holds the filter.  That filter-holder can then be updated via mutate methods on its notifier.

Comment: Thanks, to be more clear: in StateNotifier I can pass an initial value, then I can mutate the state without being affected by this initial value as it's not recomputed again, but (as far as I know) in new Notifier/AsyncNotifier classes, the initial value is determined by the build method... how I can pass an initial value to the Notifier class from outside  without using it as a family like what I can do in StateNotifier. Thanks so much.

Comment: It's either gonna derive from something the family key is relating to, or it's gonna be an internal default data value, or it's gonna be the value of a provider via ref.watch.  That's how you select an initial value.